# PhpMyAdmin on Ubuntu Server 10.04: Strange configuration issues

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

### My situation

I recently installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server on a virtual machine. I installed apache2, php and mysql. Several vhosts I sat up are running fine and I can also connect to the MySQL server using the `mysql` command-line client.

I now want to setup PhpMyAdmin to allow the vhosts owners to administrate their DBs. I installed the package using `apt-get install phpmyadmin`. I answered the questions and accepted the creation of the `phpmyadmin` database. The install finished successfully.

I did a small modification to the main website vhost to access it easily:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

I can now access the interface and login with my root user.

### My problem

The problem is that on the bottom it says that I need to add a blowfish_secret to the server configuration. I've done it once in Fedora but here it's different. I tried to add it at the end of the `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` and to reload apache and clear the browser cache but it had absolutely no effect (the message is still here). I also noticed several other files :

- `/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php` (apparently contains config needed to access the phpmyadmin database)
- `/var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` (empty!?)
- `/var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php` (contains a correct blowfish_secret config line and was already there from the beginning)

I don't know where to do the blowfish configuration. Could someone explain in details or give a link about the configuration layout of phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 10.04 ?

I also have a second problem which is probably related. It says on the bottom that some features are disabled. I read somewhere that this line should be added:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
```

but I don't know where to put it. Again, it has no effect when put in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.

I can provide the files if needed. Please just ask in a comment.

PS: The default installation works like a charm on my Ubuntu Desktop 10.10 laptop. No error messages and warning on the web interface.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my honest opinion:

Uninstall PHPMyAdmin (I'm guessing you installed it via `apt-get`.

I've seen this happen and I pulled my hair out.  What I recommend is, downloading PHPMyAdmin from [their](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) website and extract it to `/etc/phpmyadmin`.  Then I'd change your Apache alias to

`Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin`

From there, restart apache and you should be good.

One quick thing, you will need to edit the `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file (which will need to be renamed upon installation, by the way - originally it is called `config.sample.inc.php`). You basically, will need to edit the `$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '';` section with random letters/numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You probably meant Alias "/phpmyadmin /etc/phpmyadmin". I would put it somewhere else like /opt/ though. I would prefer to use the one available in apt because it would be easier for the updates. I will do that if I can't find any other solution...

Comment: Ya, that's what I meant.  Updates would be generally easier, but not that rough with a manual installation, as you would basically just overwrite the files (except the config.inc.php file). The one that comes with apt caused alot of issues on my end and I ended getting fed up with it.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work too on Ubuntu via apt-get which stores the blowfish_secret variable in a file called blowfish_secret.inc.php, however the config.inc.php does not reference it in any way and does not work if you reference it in PHP's include() or require() functions within the config.inc.php file. I have also tried to just place it within the config.inc.php file by adding the line $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'HashGoesHere'; and no go. What Drew says above with the manual install is probably the only solution.